# Postgresql: Limits of tsquery field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, full-text-search, plpgsql

I'm using a tsquery field in order to pre-compute batch searches, but I'm encountering this error while updating a tsquery field on a table:

```
ERROR:  row is too big: size 10704, maximum size 8160
```

The error is given when I'm updating the field with the resulting tsquery of a long string (2439 ASCII chars, with no multibyte char). My guess is that the tsquery it's a binary format and its weight is higher than the original string, maybe because of additional information stored by the format.

There seems to be no limit imposed by the to_tsquery() function itself, but the limit is imposed for the field size, though,

Here is the field definition:

```
ALTER TABLE public.tpl ADD content_ts_query TSQUERY NULL;
```

Is it possible to change this setting? If not, how long can be the string so it can fit it inside the field?

Pg version: 9.3

Comment: I've seen this error not from the table column, but rather from the index on it.  Do you have an index on this column?  If you have a gist index, try changing it to gin.

Comment: Sadly, it's not the case. There are no indexes on that column.

Comment: Yes, I see that tsquery is not toastable.  I don't know why that decision was made.  You could making the column be a text column, and then cast the tsquery to text before storage and cast it back to tsquery on use.